# How to avoid NLTK's sentence tokenizer splitting on abbreviations?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm currently using NLTK for language processing, but I have encountered a problem of sentence tokenizing.

Here's the problem:
Assume I have a sentence: "Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A. map."
When I use punkt tokenizer, my code looks like this:

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
punkt_param = PunktParameters()
abbreviation = ['U.S.A', 'fig']
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(abbreviation)
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
tokenizer.tokenize('Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A. map.')
```

It returns this:

```
['Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A.', 'map.']
```

The tokenizer can't detect the abbreviation "U.S.A.", but it worked on "fig".
Now when I use the default tokenizer NLTK provides:

```
import nltk
nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize('Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A. map.')
```

This time I get:

```
['Fig.', '2 shows a U.S.A. map.']
```

It recognizes the more common "U.S.A." but fails to see "fig"!

How can I combine these two methods? I want to use default abbreviation choices as well as adding my own abbreviations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think **lower case for u.s.a** in abbreviations list will work fine for you
Try this,

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
punkt_param = PunktParameters()
abbreviation = ['u.s.a', 'fig']
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(abbreviation)
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
tokenizer.tokenize('Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A. map.')
```

It returns this to me:

```
['Fig. 2 shows a U.S.A. map.']
```