# How to improve NLTK sentence segmentation?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, text-segmentation

Given the paragraph from Wikipedia:

> An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr. Vernon F.
> Gallagher in 1952. Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was
> opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958,
> housing the schools of business and law. It was during the tenure of
> F. Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to
> action.

I run NLTK `nltk.sent_tokenize` to get the sentences. This returns:

```
['An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr.', 
'Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952.', 
'Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law.', 
'It was during the tenure of Fr.', 
'Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action.'
 ]
```

While NTLK could handle **F. Henry J. McAnulty** as one entity,
It failed for **Fr. Vernon F. Gallagher**, and this broke the sentence into two.

The correct tokenization should be:

```
[
'An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr. Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952.', 
'Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law.', 
'It was during the tenure of Fr. Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action.'
 ]
```

How can I improve the tokenizer performance?

Comment: This is probably something you should ask the devs directly...

Comment: What is the output that you've got for the input sentence?

Comment: Could you share the full text that you want to sentence tokenize?

Comment: @alvas the input text is the plain text from Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duquesne_University

Comment: @alvas the output for the small paragraph I posted was ['An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr.', 
'Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952.', 
'Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law.', 
'It was during the tenure of Fr.', 
'Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action.']

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The awesome-ness of Kiss and Strunk (2006) Punkt algorithm is that it's unsupervised. So given a new text, you should retrain the model and apply the model to your text, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
>>> text = "An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr. Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952. Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law. It was during the tenure of F. Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action."

# Training a new model with the text.
>>> tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.train(text)
<nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktParameters object at 0x106c5d828>

# It automatically learns the abbreviations.
>>> tokenizer._params.abbrev_types
{'f', 'fr', 'j'}

# Use the customized tokenizer.
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(text)
['An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr. Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952.', 'Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law.', "It was during the tenure of F. Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action."]
```

Where there's not enough data to generate good statistics when re-training the model, you can also put in a pre-determined list of abbreviations before training; see [How to avoid NLTK's sentence tokenizer spliting on abbreviations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805790/how-to-avoid-nltks-sentence-tokenizer-spliting-on-abbreviations)

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters

>>> punkt_param = PunktParameters()
>>> abbreviation = ['f', 'fr', 'k']
>>> punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(abbreviation)

>>> tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
>>> tokenizer.train(text)
<nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktParameters object at 0x106c5d828>

>>> tokenizer.tokenize(text)
['An ambitious campus expansion plan was proposed by Fr. Vernon F. Gallagher in 1952.', 'Assumption Hall, the first student dormitory, was opened in 1954, and Rockwell Hall was dedicated in November 1958, housing the schools of business and law.', "It was during the tenure of F. Henry J. McAnulty that Fr. Gallagher's ambitious plans were put to action."]
```

Comment: Can I pass a pre-determined list of abbreviations to the default Punkt model? (without re-training)

Comment: Always retrain, it doesn't hurt and it might be a better option than using a pre-trained model.

Comment: Try to get away from the supervised learning mentality of train -> infer. And imagine "customized everything" in unsupervised-land =)

Comment: Thank you :) while I am working on the entire Wikipedia, I am curious to know if it is sufficient to re-train per article, or to train a model beforehand on all articles?

Comment: Try both, it's not that expensive =) Please do share which get better results after re-training!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will :)